# Change "eslint:recommended" to warnings

Tags: eslint

I am using

```
"extends": "eslint:recommended",
```

in my `.eslintrc`file. These rules fail the lint by default. Is there a way for me to change all of them to warnings without having to specify each one individually? So, is there a way to change the rule level en-masse for an extended rule set?

For example, I would love to be able to do something like:

```
"extends": [
  ["eslint:recommended", 1]
],
```

Comment: Nope thats is not possible. Only way  is to mention each rule and set them to warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by @Gyandeep, no: http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html#configuring-rules

I wrote a script to make it a little less painful for you:

```
#!/bin/sh

list=$(curl -silent http://eslint.org/docs/rules/ | grep '(recommended)' | sed -e 's,.*<a .*>\([^<]*\)</a>.*,\1,g' | grep -v 'configuration documentation')

for rule in ${list}; do
    echo \"$rule\": 1,
done;
```

That'll result in:

```
"comma-dangle": 1,
"no-cond-assign": 1,
"no-console": 1,
"no-constant-condition": 1,
"no-control-regex": 1,
"no-debugger": 1,
"no-dupe-args": 1,
"no-dupe-keys": 1,
"no-duplicate-case": 1,
"no-empty-character-class": 1,
"no-empty": 1,
"no-ex-assign": 1,
"no-extra-boolean-cast": 1,
"no-extra-semi": 1,
"no-func-assign": 1,
"no-inner-declarations": 1,
"no-invalid-regexp": 1,
"no-irregular-whitespace": 1,
"no-negated-in-lhs": 1,
"no-obj-calls": 1,
"no-regex-spaces": 1,
"no-sparse-arrays": 1,
"no-unreachable": 1,
"use-isnan": 1,
"valid-typeof": 1,
"no-fallthrough": 1,
"no-octal": 1,
"no-redeclare": 1,
"no-delete-var": 1,
"no-undef": 1,
"no-unused-vars": 1,
"no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": 1,
```

If you look here: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/ you'll note the rules included by `eslint:recommended` are followed by `(recommended)`. The script pulls the website, geps the lines with `(recommended)` then uses `sed` to do some regex magic that extracts the rule from the anchor tags.

Don't forget to take out the last `,` - I have to leave something for you to do ;) - and insert this in your `.eslintrc` file between:

```
"rules": {
   ...output of script goes here...
}
```

If you're not familiar with bash scripts, don't forget to make it executable... even easier, just copy the output I pasted above! :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the idea and the script!

Comment: Sounds like they changed the website style, hence it's not working anymore.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the eslint plugin [eslint-plugin-only-warn](https://github.com/bfanger/eslint-plugin-only-warn) if you need to change all ESLint errors to warnings.

If you still need some rules to trigger a full error, you could try this fork of only-warn, 
[eslint-plugin-switch-error-warn](https://github.com/finnmerlett/eslint-plugin-switch-error-warn) (disclaimer - I am the fork author). It switches errors to warnings and visa versa, so you can set specific rules to "warn" to make them trigger errors again. This will give you the added functionality to specify exceptions, though it might get rather confusing!

You will also need to set any rules that default to warning (such as 'no-console') to 'error' mode explicitly, to get them to only give warnings with the switcher plugin.

Answer (score 4):

I know am late for the party, but as the accepted answer got expired due to structure changes of the `eslint` website,I've created a new list with all rules set to `warn`

```
//React ESLint
"react/boolean-prop-naming": "warn",
"react/button-has-type": "warn",
"react/default-props-match-prop-types": "warn",
"react/destructuring-assignment": "warn",
"react/display-name": "warn",
"react/forbid-component-props": "warn",
"react/forbid-dom-props": "warn",
"react/forbid-elements": "warn",
"react/forbid-prop-types": "warn",
"react/forbid-foreign-prop-types": "warn",
"react/no-access-state-in-setstate": "warn",
"react/no-array-index-key": "warn",
"react/no-children-prop": "warn",
"react/no-danger": "warn",
"react/no-danger-with-children": "warn",
"react/no-deprecated": "warn",
"react/no-did-mount-set-state": "warn",
"react/no-did-update-set-state": "warn",
"react/no-direct-mutation-state": "warn",
"react/no-find-dom-node": "warn",
"react/no-is-mounted": "warn",
"react/no-multi-comp": "warn",
"react/no-redundant-should-component-update": "warn",
"react/no-render-return-value": "warn",
"react/no-set-state": "warn",
"react/no-typos": "warn",
"react/no-string-refs": "warn",
"react/no-this-in-sfc": "warn",
"react/no-unescaped-entities": "warn",
"react/no-unknown-property": "warn",
"react/no-unused-prop-types": "warn",
"react/no-unused-state": "warn",
"react/no-will-update-set-state": "warn",
"react/prefer-es6-class": "warn",
"react/prop-types": "warn",
"react/react-in-jsx-scope": "warn",
"react/require-default-props": "warn",
"react/require-optimization": "warn",
"react/require-render-return": "warn",
"react/self-closing-comp": "warn",
"react/sort-comp": "warn",
"react/sort-prop-types": "warn",
"react/style-prop-object": "warn",
"react/void-dom-elements-no-children": "warn",
"react/jsx-boolean-value": "warn",
"react/jsx-child-element-spacing": "warn",
"react/jsx-closing-bracket-location": "warn",
"react/jsx-closing-tag-location": "warn",
"react/jsx-curly-spacing": "warn",
"react/jsx-equals-spacing": "warn",
"react/jsx-first-prop-new-line": "warn",
"react/jsx-handler-names": "warn",
"react/jsx-indent": "warn",
"react/jsx-indent-props": "warn",
"react/jsx-key": "warn",
"react/jsx-max-depth": "warn",
"react/jsx-max-props-per-line": "warn",
"react/jsx-no-bind": "warn",
"react/jsx-no-comment-textnodes": "warn",
"react/jsx-no-duplicate-props": "warn",
"react/jsx-no-literals": "warn",
"react/jsx-no-target-blank": "warn",
"react/jsx-no-undef": "warn",
"react/jsx-one-expression-per-line": "warn",
"react/jsx-curly-brace-presence": "warn",
"react/jsx-pascal-case": "warn",
"react/jsx-props-no-multi-spaces": "warn",
"react/jsx-sort-default-props": "warn",
"react/jsx-sort-props": "warn",
"react/jsx-space-before-closing": "warn",
"react/jsx-tag-spacing": "warn",
"react/jsx-uses-react": "warn",
"react/jsx-uses-vars": "warn",
"react/jsx-wrap-multilines": "warn",

// Default ESLint
"for-direction": "warn",
"getter-return": "warn",
"no-await-in-loop": "warn",
"no-compare-neg-zero": "warn",
"no-cond-assign": "warn",
"no-console": "warn",
"no-constant-condition": "warn",
"no-control-regex": "warn",
"no-debugger": "warn",
"no-dupe-args": "warn",
"no-dupe-keys": "warn",
"no-duplicate-case": "warn",
"no-empty": "warn",
"no-empty-character-class": "warn",
"no-ex-assign": "warn",
"no-extra-boolean-cast": "warn",
"no-extra-parens": "warn",
"no-extra-semi": "warn",
"no-func-assign": "warn",
"no-inner-declarations": "warn",
"no-invalid-regexp": "warn",
"no-irregular-whitespace": "warn",
"no-obj-calls": "warn",
"no-prototype-builtins": "warn",
"no-regex-spaces": "warn",
"no-sparse-arrays": "warn",
"no-template-curly-in-string": "warn",
"no-unexpected-multiline": "warn",
"no-unreachable": "warn",
"no-unsafe-finally": "warn",
"no-unsafe-negation": "warn",
"use-isnan": "warn",
"valid-jsdoc": "warn",
"valid-typeof": "warn",
"accessor-pairs": "warn",
"array-callback-return": "warn",
"block-scoped-var": "warn",
"class-methods-use-this": "warn",
"complexity": "warn",
"consistent-return": "warn",
"curly": "warn",
"default-case": "warn",
"dot-location": "warn",
"dot-notation": "warn",
"eqeqeq": "warn",
"guard-for-in": "warn",
"max-classes-per-file": "warn",
"no-alert": "warn",
"no-caller": "warn",
"no-case-declarations": "warn",
"no-div-regex": "warn",
"no-else-return": "warn",
"no-empty-function": "warn",
"no-empty-pattern": "warn",
"no-eq-null": "warn",
"no-eval": "warn",
"no-extend-native": "warn",
"no-extra-bind": "warn",
"no-extra-label": "warn",
"no-fallthrough": "warn",
"no-floating-decimal": "warn",
"no-global-assign": "warn",
"no-implicit-coercion": "warn",
"no-implicit-globals": "warn",
"no-implied-eval": "warn",
"no-invalid-this": "warn",
"no-iterator": "warn",
"no-labels": "warn",
"no-lone-blocks": "warn",
"no-loop-func": "warn",
"no-magic-numbers": "warn",
"no-multi-spaces": "warn",
"no-multi-str": "warn",
"no-new": "warn",
"no-new-func": "warn",
"no-new-wrappers": "warn",
"no-octal": "warn",
"no-octal-escape": "warn",
"no-param-reassign": "warn",
"no-proto": "warn",
"no-redeclare": "warn",
"no-restricted-properties": "warn",
"no-return-assign": "warn",
"no-return-await": "warn",
"no-script-url": "warn",
"no-self-assign": "warn",
"no-self-compare": "warn",
"no-sequences": "warn",
"no-throw-literal": "warn",
"no-unmodified-loop-condition": "warn",
"no-unused-expressions": "warn",
"no-unused-labels": "warn",
"no-useless-call": "warn",
"no-useless-concat": "warn",
"no-useless-escape": "warn",
"no-useless-return": "warn",
"no-void": "warn",
"no-warning-comments": "warn",
"no-with": "warn",
"prefer-promise-reject-errors": "warn",
"radix": "warn",
"require-await": "warn",
"vars-on-top": "warn",
"wrap-iife": "warn",
"yoda": "warn",
"strict": "warn",
"init-declarations": "warn",
"no-catch-shadow": "warn",
"no-delete-var": "warn",
"no-label-var": "warn",
"no-restricted-globals": "warn",
"no-shadow": "warn",
"no-shadow-restricted-names": "warn",
"no-undef": "warn",
"no-undef-init": "warn",
"no-undefined": "warn",
"no-unused-vars": "warn",
"no-use-before-define": "warn",
"callback-return": "warn",
"global-require": "warn",
"handle-callback-err": "warn",
"no-buffer-constructor": "warn",
"no-mixed-requires": "warn",
"no-new-require": "warn",
"no-path-concat": "warn",
"no-process-env": "warn",
"no-process-exit": "warn",
"no-restricted-modules": "warn",
"no-sync": "warn",
"array-bracket-newline": "warn",
"array-bracket-spacing": "warn",
"array-element-newline": "warn",
"block-spacing": "warn",
"brace-style": "warn",
"camelcase": "warn",
"capitalized-comments": "warn",
"comma-dangle": "warn",
"comma-spacing": "warn",
"comma-style": "warn",
"computed-property-spacing": "warn",
"consistent-this": "warn",
"eol-last": "warn",
"func-call-spacing": "warn",
"func-name-matching": "warn",
"func-names": "warn",
"func-style": "warn",
"function-paren-newline": "warn",
"id-blacklist": "warn",
"id-length": "warn",
"id-match": "warn",
"implicit-arrow-linebreak": "warn",
"indent": "warn",
"jsx-quotes": "warn",
"key-spacing": "warn",
"keyword-spacing": "warn",
"line-comment-position": "warn",
"linebreak-style": "warn",
"lines-around-comment": "warn",
"lines-between-class-members": "warn",
"max-depth": "warn",
"max-len": "warn",
"max-lines": "warn",
"max-nested-callbacks": "warn",
"max-params": "warn",
"max-statements": "warn",
"max-statements-per-line": "warn",
"multiline-comment-style": "warn",
"multiline-ternary": "warn",
"new-cap": "warn",
"new-parens": "warn",
"newline-per-chained-call": "warn",
"no-array-constructor": "warn",
"no-bitwise": "warn",
"no-continue": "warn",
"no-inline-comments": "off",
"no-lonely-if": "warn",
"no-mixed-operators": "warn",
"no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": "warn",
"no-multi-assign": "warn",
"no-multiple-empty-lines": "warn",
"no-negated-condition": "warn",
"no-nested-ternary": "warn",
"no-new-object": "warn",
"no-plusplus": "warn",
"no-restricted-syntax": "warn",
"no-tabs": "warn",
"no-ternary": "warn",
"no-trailing-spaces": "warn",
"no-underscore-dangle": "warn",
"no-unneeded-ternary": "warn",
"no-whitespace-before-property": "warn",
"nonblock-statement-body-position": "warn",
"object-curly-newline": "warn",
"object-curly-spacing": "warn",
"object-property-newline": "warn",
"one-var": "warn",
"one-var-declaration-per-line": "warn",
"operator-assignment": "warn",
"operator-linebreak": "warn",
"padded-blocks": "warn",
"padding-line-between-statements": "warn",
"prefer-object-spread": "warn",
"quote-props": "warn",
"quotes": "warn",
"require-jsdoc": "warn",
"semi": "warn",
"semi-spacing": "warn",
"semi-style": "warn",
"sort-keys": "warn",
"sort-vars": "warn",
"space-before-blocks": "warn",
"space-before-function-paren": "warn",
"space-in-parens": "warn",
"space-infix-ops": "warn",
"space-unary-ops": "warn",
"spaced-comment": "warn",
"switch-colon-spacing": "warn",
"template-tag-spacing": "warn",
"unicode-bom": "warn",
"wrap-regex": "warn",
"arrow-body-style": "warn",
"arrow-parens": "warn",
"arrow-spacing": "warn",
"constructor-super": "warn",
"generator-star-spacing": "warn",
"no-class-assign": "warn",
"no-confusing-arrow": "warn",
"no-const-assign": "warn",
"no-dupe-class-members": "warn",
"no-duplicate-imports": "warn",
"no-new-symbol": "warn",
"no-restricted-imports": "warn",
"no-this-before-super": "warn",
"no-useless-computed-key": "warn",
"no-useless-constructor": "warn",
"no-useless-rename": "warn",
"no-var": "warn",
"object-shorthand": "warn",
"prefer-arrow-callback": "warn",
"prefer-const": "warn",
"prefer-destructuring": "warn",
"prefer-numeric-literals": "warn",
"prefer-rest-params": "warn",
"prefer-spread": "warn",
"prefer-template": "warn",
"require-yield": "warn",
"rest-spread-spacing": "warn",
"sort-imports": "warn",
"symbol-description": "warn",
"template-curly-spacing": "warn",
"yield-star-spacing": "warn"
```

Comment: Since these rules might change. Here is the linkt to the file on GitHub: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/conf/eslint-recommended.js